# Received SMS/MMS with suspicious link - what to do now?

Tags: malware, virus, sms, trojan

I today received a personalized sms on my android phone which:

- addresses me by my first name
- is labeled sms/mms
- claims to be from a contact with a first name which I do not have in my contact list, but with whom I had a call 2 hours before
- answering is not possible like in other sms (keyboard not shown)
- contains a suspicious link on .ms domain

**Questions:**

1. What should I do now?
2. How can I find out more about the sender?
3. Am I infected already just by opening the sms (not the link)?

Comment: Do this: Delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not yet infected, but opening the link will most probably infect you (or attempt to).

What you should do open and analyze the link from a secure container (this is how you find more info on what's there and what the purpose of it is) and delete it from your device.

Comment: Ok, but why is my keyboard disabled only in that message?

Comment: Actually the possibility to answer is disabled because there is no clear destination to answer to. It's something similar to hidden number calls. You receive the call, but you cannot call back because the number is not known to you.